# React-router (v4) negate double forward slashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Given that this is a working url with the correct routing using react-router-v4 and browserhistory:

> https://localhost:8020/User/Category

My code implemnetation does it right, but what if the user makes the following error whilst composing the url manually:

> http://localhost:8020/User//Category (double forward slash)

Is there a way we can treat double slashes as one without having to manually catch them as a valid route? I've seen multiple websites with this behaviour.

I tried creating my own custom middleware to intercept the location changes and fix it but i'm having a lot of dificulties typing it, so I want to know if there's an (easy) alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are defining routes?

Comment: Any luck with this? pl share if you found the solution

Answer (score 2):

So you're saying what if the user ends up going to `/user//category?` In this case, the browser treats multiple consecutive forward slashes and treats them as one. Try google.com///mail. Should still take you to google.com/mail. Therefore you shouldn't need to change anything on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the info! My relative pathing causes no issue, am just getting the question if there's an easy way to make double forward slashes behave like one .. I must've mistyped my question, i'll try to clear it up

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the beginning of your `Switch`:

```
<Redirect from={`User//:name`} to={`User/:name`} />
```

or better, if you use

```
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
```

then use:

```
<Redirect from={`${path}//:name`} to={`${path}/:name`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to an issue I had this morning.  I would get a double slash if I went from `localhost:3000/home/` (`localhost:3000:3000/home//navigation`), but a single from `localhost:3000/home` (`localhost:3000/home/navigation`).  I solved it by wrapping my links in a ternary operator and checking if the last char in the current path was a '/'.

```
(this.props.match.path.slice(-1) === '/') ? `${this.props.match.path}navigation` : `${this.props.match.path}/navigation`
```

I don't know if this could help with your issue?

Comment: This works, but this should not be happening in the first place, therefore this is a patch for buggy code somewhere in your app. Do not recommend this approach and encourage you to find the root cause

Comment: Found it.  We weren't using relative links... oops!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Excellent! That definitely sounds like the case, since the browser/react-router would automatically add a leading slash if you don't

Comment: Hey I am using relative links and have no issues with that, it's more , what if the user makes a typo in the url? (I have clarified my question)